# Importing date to mySql from CSV file

Tags: php, mysql

My son set up a facility on his hosted site for the family to record data from trips in a MySql file. These are then displayed on a web page on a map (uses google maps but is hosted privately.)

Unfortunately my son was taken in to hospital some weeks ago and is still there, so he suggested  may get an answer to a problem if I posted it here.

The mysql data is created by using a php script to import it from csv files produced by loggers. My son unfortunately cannot remember where he obtained the script.

This script works EXCEPT for a date field (which is crucial).

The Script is as follows:

```
$tot = 0;
$handle = fopen($_FILES["uploaded"]["tmp_name"], "r");
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    for ($c=0; $c < 1; $c++) {

if($data[0] !='Latitude'){ 
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO positions(
                Latitude,
                Longitude,
                DateOccurred,
                Altitude,
                Speed,
                Angle
                )VALUES(
                    '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[0])."',
                    '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[1])."',
                    '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[2])."',
                    '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[16])."',
                    '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[15])."',
                    '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[8])."'

                )")or die(mysql_error());
}
    $tot++;}
}
fclose($handle);
```

This imports everything to mysql EXCEPT for the the third item ($data[2]) which is the date and imports as zeros (ie 00:00:00 00:00).

Are there any kind coders here who may be able to tell me how to correct this, or point me elsewhere that may be able to help.

If further info is required, please let me know.

Thanks

EDIT:
Here is the sql table structure

```
|//**ID**//|int(11)|No|
|FK_Users_ID|int(11)|No|
|FK_Trips_ID|int(11)|Yes|NULL
|FK_Icons_ID|int(11)|Yes|NULL
|Latitude|double|No|
|Longitude|double|No|
|Altitude|double|Yes|0
|Speed|double|Yes|0
|Angle|double|Yes|NULL
|DateAdded|timestamp|No|CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
|DateOccurred|timestamp|Yes|0000-00-00 00:00:00
|Comments|varchar(255)|Yes|NULL
|ImageURL|varchar(255)|Yes|NULL
|SignalStrength|int(11)|Yes|NULL
|SignalStrengthMax|int(11)|Yes|NULL
|SignalStrengthMin|int(11)|Yes|NULL
|BatteryStatus|tinyint(4)|Yes|NULL
```

Here is a sample of the CSV file content:

```
Latitude,Longitude,DateOccurred,ID,IconName,Comments,TripName,ImageURL,Angle,CellID,SignalStrength,SignalStrengthMin,SignalStrengthMax,BatteryStatus,Source,Speed,Altitude
51.1923274,-3.102753383,20/03/2013 14:17,2352,,,dentist,,287.2,,,,,,0,7.71666666,13
51.19254205,-3.103862483,20/03/2013 14:17,2353,,,dentist,,285.4,,,,,,0,7.665222216,14
51.19268602,-3.105032683,20/03/2013 14:17,2354,,,dentist,,272.1,,,,,,0,9.054222214,11.1
```

If anything else is needed, let me know.

Thanks

**EDIT 2**

I tried the solution from Havelock - option 3.

As it was still returning zeros in the DateOccurred field I added another instruction to insert the date from the csv into a 'comments' text field in the mysql database.

Code is as follows

```
if($data[0] !='Latitude'){ 
           $timestamp = strtotime($data[2]);
           mysql_query("INSERT INTO positions(
           Latitude,
           Longitude,
           DateOccurred,
           Comments,
           Altitude,
           Speed,
           Angle
           )VALUES(
               '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[0])."',
               '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[1])."',
               '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[2])."',
               '".mysql_real_escape_string(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp))."',
               '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[16])."',
               '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[15])."',
               '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[8])."'

                )")or die(mysql_error());
```

The result was that the data inserted into the 'Comments' field in all records read

```
1969-12-31 18:00:00
```

whereas the information in the csv was

```
20/03/2013 14:17
```

If I omit the lines

```
$timestamp = strtotime($data[2]);
and 
'".mysql_real_escape_string(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp))."',
```

the comments field contains the correct data from the csv file (as text).

I'm not sure how signifcant this info is - but I thought it might mean something here.

**EDIT 3**

As the 'DateTime::createFromFormat()' should work with PHP 5.3.22 I revisited the script and entered some code to test it.
I added this

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', $data[2]);
           echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

The echo was to print the results to see what they were.
The script now looks like this

```
if($data[0] !='Latitude'){ 
           $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', $data[2]);
           echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
           mysql_query("INSERT INTO positions(
           Latitude,
           Longitude,
           DateOccurred,
           Altitude,
           Speed,
           Angle
           )VALUES(
               '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[0])."',
               '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[1])."',
               '".mysql_real_escape_string(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))."',
               '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[16])."',
               '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[15])."',
               '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[8])."'


                )")or die(mysql_error());
}
```

This resulted in the script printing a date and entering it in the correct format in the mysql field.

HOWEVER -  the date that is being printed and stored is ***current date and time***, not the date stored in the csv file, so the statement seems to be ignoring $data[2}

Comment: Can you add detail from MySQL such as running: describe positions;

That may provide some useful information regarding the table schema. Aside from that, it's possible the source of that form data is not being handled properly and causing the 'default' value to be used rather than the uploaded content. You could try showing some CSV data?

Comment: What is the date format in the CSV file?

Comment: `$data[2]` is date, which format?

Comment: post an example few lines of the CSV file and this will help work out how to handle it

Comment: Simply replace the line `'".mysql_real_escape_string(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))."',` with `'".mysql_real_escape_string($date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))."',`. As it is now you're creating the date correctly from the input, but you're inserting something else - that is a freshly created date with `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`.

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
// ...

$formatFromFile = 'Y-m-d'; // your format of date in csv file
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($formatFromFile, $data[2]);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO positions(
            Latitude,
            Longitude,
            DateOccurred,
            Altitude,
            Speed,
            Angle
            )VALUES(
                '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[0])."',
                '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[1])."',
                '".mysql_real_escape_string($date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))."',
                '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[16])."',
                '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[15])."',
                '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[8])."'

            )")or die(mysql_error());
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to create a DateTime object and then output it in a MySQL-readable way. For example, suppose your date is written in the format 'dmY', e.g. '10012010' for January, 10th 2010. To learn more about the format specification read the PHP's spec page linked above.

You could use the following function to convert from 'dmY' format to mysql-format

```
function convert($date) {
  $d = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmY', $date);
  return $d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

On a side note, I suggest you take a look at MySQL's [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) which is a much faster option to import a cvs file into a table.

Comment: Thanks for the info and link to 'LOAD DATA INFILE'. I'll have a look at this with my son when/if he gets out of hospital. In the meantime I'll play with some of the answers here.

Answer (score 0):

It's depends on the format of the date on the CSV file.
Read about the function strtotime, maybe it's the solucion

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me the problem is due to the different format of the date / time in your CSV file. From the info about wrong data inserted in the table, I'd assume the type of that column is `DATETIME`. This type has the following formatting `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`, so if you have the date in the CSV file in a fomrat similar to `05/23/2012 5:35 p.m.` or something else, which isn't the expected format, it's understandable that the problem occurs. In my opinion, you have two options:

**Option 1:**
Save the date in your CSV file, so it can be conform to MySQL's [`DATETIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html). That is something like

```
2013-03-23 15:45:25
```

Then the insert should work properly.

**Option 2:**
This option might be more "fiddlier" than the previous, especially if you're not that way inclined (from reading the full text of the question). You'd need to create a new `DateTime` object in the PHP script and use its `format()` method when saving the data.
Unfortunately I don't know the format from the CSV file so I can just make a wild guess. Supposing the date in your file is formatted like this `03/24/2013 5:24 PM`

```
if($data[0] !='Latitude'){ 
           $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y g:i a', $data[2]);
           mysql_query("INSERT INTO positions(
           Latitude,
           Longitude,
           DateOccurred,
           Altitude,
           Speed,
           Angle
           )VALUES(
               '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[0])."',
               '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[1])."',
               '".mysql_real_escape_string($date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))."',
               '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[16])."',
               '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[15])."',
               '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[8])."'

           )")or die(mysql_error());
}
```

If I'm wrong about the format in the CSV file, that is the `'m/d/Y g:i a'` part, you can have a look at the [DateTime documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to see how to fix it by choosing an appropriate format, so it fits your case.

**Option 3:**
As you seem to have PHP version < 5.3 installed on your hosting server, try the following:

```
if($data[0] !='Latitude'){ 
           $timestamp = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $data[2]));
           mysql_query("INSERT INTO positions(
           Latitude,
           Longitude,
           DateOccurred,
           Altitude,
           Speed,
           Angle
           )VALUES(
               '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[0])."',
               '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[1])."',
               '".mysql_real_escape_string(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp))."',
               '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[16])."',
               '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[15])."',
               '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[8])."'

           )")or die(mysql_error());
}
```

**Update**
I've edited the `$timestamp` related line to match the format supplied by your CSV file.

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately it breaks the script with an error --- [23-Mar-2013 11:05:26 America/Chicago] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function format() on a non-object in /domain.com/sql/uploadcsv3.php on line 59 --- which is the line replaced for $data2

Comment: I see. That would suggest that you have PHP version < 5.3 installed on your hosting server. See the updated answer - `Option 3`

Comment: Thanks, you are correct, the server has PHP version 5.3.22 installed from what I can see. The script now works again with the new changes, but unfortunately is still returning zeros to the DateOccurred field ;-(. I also tried something else to see if I could see an obvious problem - details in a further edit to my original question.

Comment: Wait, if you have PHP version 5.3.22 there shouldn't be a problem neither with `DateTime::createFromFormat()`, nor with `$date->format()`. Anyhow, the problem you're having with the `Option 3` is because of the formatting of your string. See the updated line `$timestamp = strtotime(strreplace('/', '-', $data[2]));`, it should have fixed the problem. If you're curious to know more about why - see the [Documentation -> Notes -> 3rd Note](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: Sorry I didn't reply sooner, but I had to go see my sone in hospital.
Unfortunately using 'strtotime(strreplace('/', '-', $data[2]));' broke the script again.
ERROR - 'PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function strreplace() in /domain.com/sql/uploadcsv7.php on line 48'
However your comment saying 'DateTime::createFromFormat(), nor with $date->format()' should work with PHP V5.3.22 got me thinking and after I read the Documentation I tried again. The results are in a further edit to my original question.

Comment: Sorry - a correction to my previous reply. Using 'strtotime(strreplace('/', '-', $data[2]));' DOES work - if I use 'str_replace' instead. (Found this example in a document in Google search). However I would still be interested in getting the 'DateTime::createFromFormat' option working - just out of interest.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I'm sorry! Don't know what I've been looking at / thinking of yestarday. Of course it's `str_replace()`. Edited the code above.